# Q: I need idea to display a string with css, jquery or any other techniques (no php)

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a big problem. I have a mysql database which contains 12 character length fields. I would like to display somehow.

Sample data from the field:

233215334523

I would like to display 0 and 1 with red background 2 3 with yellow background and 4 5 with green background.

Important! I know str_split could split the string into characters, or I could use $string[1] $string[2] etc. also, but not now, because this cms use the lex parser (  you couldn't use php variables here!).

So I need some great idea how could I split virtual this 12 character length variable. The best should be some  which display these numbers with the background colors what I wrote earlier.

I hope someone could help for me, because I have no idea. Many thanks!

Comment: can you split strings in front end ?

Comment: No, I could use only the 12 character length variable at this part of cms.

Comment: You are going to need to use a client side library, I can show you solutions, but would need to know what libs you have in your project.

Comment: there is no other solution? With css or jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each character in a span, with a classname:

HTML:

```
<div id="fieldToSplit">233215334523</div>
```

javascript:

```
var element = document.getElementById("fieldToSplit")

var data = element.innerHTML.split("");

var wrappedString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length;  i++) {
   wrappedString += "<span class='shade" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</span>";
}

element.innerHTML = wrappedString;
```

CSS:

```
.shade0, .shade1 {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.shade2, .shade3 {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}

.shade4, .shade5 {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

This solution allows you to freely style each digit independently,  say you wanted a darker green for 5 than for 4.  And if later you need styles for 6,7,8, and 9, all you need to do is add classes `.shade6`, `.shade7`, `.shade8`, and `.shade9`.

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rwbm9ttn/1/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var letters = $('.source').html().split(/\s?/)

  for (var i = 0; i <= letters.length; ++i) {
    $('<span class="lt' + letters[i] + '">').html(letters[i]).appendTo(".letters");
  }
});
```

```css
.lt2 {
  background: yellow;
}
.lt3 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="source">233215334523</div>
<div class="letters"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An entirely jQuery version would be like this -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = 233215334523;
  var str = data.toString();
  var hold = '';
  for(var i = 0; i<str.length; i++)
    {
      if(str[i] == 0 || str[i] == 1)
        {
        hold = hold + '<span style="background-color: red;">'+str[i]+'</span>';
          $('.print').html(hold);
        }
      else if(str[i] == 2 || str[i] == 3)
        {
          hold = hold + '<span style="background-color: yellow;">'+str[i]+'</span>';
          $('.print').html(hold);
        }
      else if(str[i] == 4 || str[i] == 5)
        {
          hold = hold + '<span style="background-color: green;">'+str[i]+'</span>';
          $('.print').html(hold);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="print"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure jquery & CSS solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/k91ax5g9/1/

HTML

```
<div class='num'>101234567</div>
<div class='num'>1011223444</div>
<div class='num'>124413223</div>
<div class='num'>323123133</div>
```

JS

```
$(".num").each(function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    var t =$el.html();
    $el.html('');
    for(var c in t){
        var char = t[c];
        $el.append($("<span>", {'text_val': char}).html(char));
    }
});
```

CSS

```
[text_val="0"], [text_val="1"]{
    background: red;
}

[text_val="2"], [text_val="3"]{
    background: orange;
}

[text_val="4"], [text_val="5"]{
    background: green;
}
```